# Add server to SharePoint farm

Tags: server-farm, sharepoint-server, farm-setup

I have a two server `SharePoint OnPremise` farm. In the last years I built some webapps running on a separate server using SharePoint `CSOM`, which are consumed mostly by Javascript calls from SharePoint pages. Where possible I used Javascript `CSOM`, but for more complex operations/computations I moved it to a webapp.
Sometimes I found limitations using `CSOM`, e.g set `Editor` or `Modified`. I was wondering if it is possible to add a third server in the farm, using it only for those webapps, if it were part of the farm, it would be possible to use the ServerApi.

Is there a way to add another Server in order to use the Server Api?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new web sites to the IIS instance on your existing web front end(s) and use the server API. No need to spin up a new server. They will have to run on a different port however.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but is there no need or is there no way to set up a new server? It think it would be bettere to keep the load separated.